# ElasticSearch behaves different in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I have recently added a new search box to my application. It works in development, but the same feature doesn't work on the Staging or Production environment. What am I missing out, please?

I am using Elasticsearch. I have already run `bundle exec rake users:index`. I have also compared the mappings file (elastic_search_mapping.json) on development and staging. There is no difference between them.

### Issue

The development and staging database are an in-sync. However, the same Elasticsearch query returns no results on Staging whilst, the development gets a bunch of results.

Gotcha: The staging environment returns a result only when an exact matching of the query has been found. In order words, it does not allow for *fuzzy* searching.

### Plea

Can anyone point what I'm failing to do please?

```
   ## On Development
    ⤷  curl -v http://localhost:9200/red_development/users/_count?pretty -d '{
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "registered_name": "SBN"
        }
      }
    }'

    *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
    * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9200 (#0)
    > POST /red_development/users/_count?pretty HTTP/1.1
    > Host: localhost:9200
    > User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
    > Accept: */*
    > Content-Length: 72
    > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    >
    * upload completely sent off: 72 out of 72 bytes
    < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    < Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    < Content-Length: 95
    <
    {
      "count" : 3,
      "_shards" : {
        "total" : 5,
        "successful" : 5,
        "failed" : 0
      }
    }
    * Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

This is the results I get for running the same results on Staging. It returns no results.

```
    ## on Staging
    ⤷  curl -v https://xxxxx:xxxxx@foofoo5625275.eu-west-1.bonsai.io/red_production/users/_count?pretty -d '{

    >   "query": {
    >     "match": {
    >       "registered_name": "SBN"
    >     }
    >   }
    > }'
    *   Trying xx.yy.zzz.aaa...
    * Connected to foofoo5625275.eu-west-1.bonsai.io (xx.yy.zzz.aaa) port 443 (#0)
    * TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    * Server certificate: eu-west-1.bonsai.io
    * Server certificate: Amazon
    * Server certificate: Amazon Root CA 1
    * Server certificate: Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2
    * Server auth using Basic with user 'xxxxxx'
    > POST /red_production/users/_count?pretty HTTP/1.1
    > Host: foofoo5625275.eu-west-1.bonsai.io
    > Authorization: Basic aDA2czQ0Zm1ycQ==
    > User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
    > Accept: */*
    > Content-Length: 72
    > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    >
    * upload completely sent off: 72 out of 72 bytes
    < HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    < Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    < Server: Nespr 1.1
    < X-Bonsai-Backend: xx.yy.zzz.aaa
    < X-Queue-Duration: 0
    < X-Request-Duration: 3
    < X-Request-Id: 0922c231-44d8-4720-b3b1-df113bb8434f
    < Content-Length: 95
    < Connection: keep-alive
    <
    {
      "count" : 0,
      "_shards" : {
        "total" : 1,
        "successful" : 1,
        "failed" : 0
      }
    }
    * Connection #0 to host foofoo5625275.eu-west-1.bonsai.io left intact
```

Comment: Could be a difference in the data itself. Try stripping whitespace and making data as uniform as possible between development and production environments.

Comment: @moveson the database in development is an exact clone from the staging db server.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment: "Gotcha: The staging environment returns a result only when an exact matching of the query has been found. In order words, it does not allow for fuzzy searching"

It seems to me that your runtime mapping might be different; Compare:

http://localhost:9200/_mapping on both clusters. (Replace with correct address/port)